# Can we get Server Cluster real path in Java

Tags: apache, tomcat, servlets, cluster-computing

My web application is deployed on tomcat cluster. I have created a servlet that converts pdfs to images on server start up.

These images are stored on server filesystem inside the war itself, which is not a shared location. And I am using these images as part of war resource.

Accessing these images on development environment is working fine as it is non clustered environment.

Now on production environment clustered server is used. And images are not available on every cluster, during conversion.

Comment: Do you write the generated images to disk? Then you should consider using a shared medium (NFS mount, SAN) for storing. Or store them as BLOBs in your database.

Comment: @f_puras: Converted images are stored inside the war file, as I wanted to use the images created as war resource.

Comment: Are you building a separare WAR file for each member of the cluster? Generating images on startup, then re-writing the WAR file seems ... risky. Why not generate these images when you are building your WAR instead of while the webapp is starting?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz No. The WAR is common for all clusters. My app has to use to those images. So I need to convert them before my app starts. I don't have privileges to create a folder out of these cluster environment wherein I've plans to keep it as a shared resource for all clusters.

Comment: So, just to be sure, you have something like a `ServletContextListener` that extracts some data from the WAR file (or elsewhere, I guess), converts that to PDF, then modifies the WAR file the webapp is running from in order to add those PDF files into it? I'm actually surprised that the WAR file isn't locked for writing and that this works at all. So, after you do all that, some of the cluster members seem to work while others don't? Is every node running the same version of Tomcat?